# Can we create an IBOutlet to a View Controller

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, xcode4.3

I have a viewController. That viewController have a containerView that contain another controller. List and map.

I want users to be able to switch between list and map via a button.

So that means the parent view controller (or somebody) need to be able to refer to both the mapViewController and ListViewController.

How can I achieve that?

One way to do so is by using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier. However, I do not like identifier. Identifier is prone to mistyping and conflicts.  I like Outlet

I read that one possible way to do so is to set a storyboardid. What about if I like the good old outlet?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you have to sub view controllers.  What I would do is create a master controller class, which imports all of the other view controllers (think of it as the super class of the entire project) which will then control a empty view, less a button.  The background of the empty view will be fed by an "active" view, which will be supplied by either listViewController.h or mapViewController.h  This will let the users use both the list/map VC's, and be able to switch between the two.

Comment: The problem is how do I refer to that mapView?

Comment: mapView would be in a subViewController.  The master doesn't have to import anything, but rather, turn the other two on and off.

Comment: ellman, have you done this? Okay so I put a subViewController, then what? How do I draw outlet from subViewController to the code?

Comment: Heres a visual of it.  I haven't done this, but think of it like this.  The masterVC runs, and loads either list or map VC onto a stack.  When the user taps the button, it is popped off the stack, and then the other VC is loaded.  You could use a simply boolean to figure out wich VC is loaded, and then the transition would be simple.  Heres a diagram of how I would implement this.  http://imgur.com/yOadt